# Using Vue js components in typescript based project

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js

I googled a lot to no avail and it seems I'm missing something obvious but still... I've created a project in a following stack : Vue+TS+Webpack+ASP.NET Core.
 Now I'm facing a cruel reality - there are literally dozens of good Vue components, but very few of them have something like *.d.ts attached. Is there some relatively easy (rewriting it in TS IMHO is not an easy solution) way to use JS-based Vue components in technology stack mentioned above?

P.S.: If you know nice modal dialog Vue component with out-of-the-box ts support let me know please :) Though of course I prefer to hear about more general solution.

Comment: You have two possible solutions: `declare var someVueComponent:any` or write the defs yourself.

Answer (score 2):

I may not understand the whole situation but, enabling JS usage in webpack should be enough I guess.

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "allowJs": true
  }
}
```

Comment: Actually, AFAIR allowJs is from tsconfig.json. I'll give it a try, but seems I read somewhere there are problems with node packets files resolution. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Vuejs 2.5+ ships with official type declarations for TypeScript. You would have to install [ts-loader](https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-loader), update webpack and ts config and write components like these

**tsconfig.json**

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    // this aligns with Vue's browser support
    "target": "es5",
    // this enables stricter inference for data properties on `this`
    "strict": true,
    // if using webpack 2+ or rollup, to leverage tree shaking:
    "module": "es2015",
    "moduleResolution": "node"
  }
}
```

**some sample Vue component**

```
<script lang="ts">
import Vue from "vue";

export default Vue.extend({
    ...
});
</script>
```

If you use webpack and/or single component file, you would need additional settings as well.

**webpack.config.js**

```
module.exports = {
  entry: './src/main.ts', //TK a typescript file!
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, './dist'),
    publicPath: '/dist/',
    filename: 'build.js'
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.ts','.js'], //TK can't tell if this is actually necessary but is in all the sample code I found
    alias: {
      'vue$': 'vue/dist/vue.esm.js'
    }
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      // TK THE LOADER: needed to process typescript files. Note the option used. We'll also need sfc.d.ts so that typescript can find the necessary .vue files
      // TK make sure to npm install ts-loader and npm link typscript if its installed globally
      {
        test: /\.ts$/,
        exclude: /node_modules|vue\/src/,
        loader: 'ts-loader',
        options: {
          appendTsSuffixTo: [/\.vue$/]
         }
      },
...
```

in case of single file component, you would need to add this file at root
**sfc.d.ts** so that TypeScript can recognize this as module

```
declare module "*.vue" {
  import Vue from 'vue'
  export default typeof Vue
}
```

You can read more about it [here](https://medium.com/@chuckdries/using-typescript-with-vue-js-single-file-components-aaf51cbf5603)

Comment: Thanks for answer, but I have no problems using Vue with Typescript, what  really irritates is using JS-based components without proper ts declaration files.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I have seen, props can't get typed with typescript, instead when you require them you can validate them as shown at [vue prop validation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-props.html#Prop-Validation) so just search for common vue components.

By the way I'm sure you've already seen the [vue typescript support](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/typescript.html).

About components, I think the best is to choose a framework like [vuetify](https://vuetifyjs.com) or [bootstrap-vue](https://bootstrap-vue.js.org) where you will find a group of components following the same style

Answer (score 0):

I use [Vuetify](https://vuetifyjs.com/) which supports typescript, and then if I need components which isn't supported by Vuetify(which rarely happens) and by Typescript; I use `require` for instance:

```
const component = require("module"); // If component does not support TS

import component from "module"; // If component support TS
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to use js-based components in a typescript environment by disabling eslint and tslint just for those components:

1. I put all my js-based components into /js/ directory in my project.
2. I added `ignorePatterns` to `.eslintrc.js`:

```
  ignorePatterns: [
    "**/js/*.vue",
    "**/js/*.js",
  ],
```

3. I added `exclude` to `tsconfig.json`:

```
 "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "src/**/js/*.vue",
    "src/**/js/*.js"
  ]
```

That made it work.

Here is my full configs for reference:

.eslintrc.js:

```
module.exports = {
  root: true,
  env: {
    node: true
  },
  extends: [
    'plugin:vue/essential',
    'eslint:recommended',
    '@vue/typescript/recommended',
  ],
  parserOptions: {
    ecmaVersion: 2020,
    project: "./tsconfig.json",
    createDefaultProgram: true,
    async: false,
  },
  ignorePatterns: [
    "**/js/*.vue",
    "**/js/*.js",
  ],
  rules: {
    "no-throw-literal": "error",
    "no-return-await": "error",

    "@typescript-eslint/no-inferrable-types": "off",
    "@typescript-eslint/no-empty-function": "off",

    "@typescript-eslint/ban-ts-ignore": ["error"],
    "@typescript-eslint/no-non-null-assertion": "off",
    "@typescript-eslint/explicit-function-return-type": ["error"],
    "@typescript-eslint/explicit-member-accessibility": "off",
    "@typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars": ["error"],
    "@typescript-eslint/restrict-plus-operands": ["error"],
    "@typescript-eslint/restrict-template-expressions": "off",
    "@typescript-eslint/return-await": ["error", "always"],
    "@typescript-eslint/no-unsafe-call": ["error"],
    "@typescript-eslint/no-unsafe-return": ["error"],
    "@typescript-eslint/no-unsafe-member-access": ["error"],
    "@typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars-experimental": ["error"],
    "@typescript-eslint/no-unused-expressions": ["error"],
    "@typescript-eslint/unbound-method": ["error"],
    "@typescript-eslint/strict-boolean-expressions": ["error"],
    "@typescript-eslint/no-throw-literal": ["error"],

    'no-console': process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? 'warn' : 'off',
    'no-debugger': process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? 'warn' : 'off'
  }
}
```

tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "esnext",
    "module": "esnext",
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "allowJs": false,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "strict": true,
    "importHelpers": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noUnusedParameters": true,
    "strictNullChecks": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "noErrorTruncation": true,
    "strictBindCallApply": true,
    "strictFunctionTypes": true,
    "strictPropertyInitialization": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "noEmitOnError": true,
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "types": [
      "webpack-env",
      "jest"
    ],
    "paths": {
      "@/*": [
        "src/*"
      ]
    },
    "lib": [
      "esnext",
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "scripthost"
    ]
  },
  "include": [
    "src/**/*.ts",
    "src/**/*.tsx",
    "src/**/*.vue",
    "tests/**/*.ts",
    "tests/**/*.tsx"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "src/**/js/*.vue",
    "src/**/js/*.js"
  ]
}
```